# failed to run phantomjs in my tests

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, vuejs2

I followed https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack to install my project, and now I want to test it.

When I run `cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run` fails to run [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs), and I see these errors:

```
PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
Trying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).
PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
PhantomJS failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

Knowing that I've added this line into my `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/path/to/project/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

And in my terminal:

```
 --> phantomjs -v
 2.1.1
```

Comment: Please paste karma conf. Do you have `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: No, I just added it and it works!! thx. Please add an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma by default listens on `localhost` and will fail without a meaningful error if it can't be resolved. At some point you've probably removed `127.0.0.1 localhost` from `/etc/hosts` - try to re-add it, it should help.

Credit goes to [zewish](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/84#issuecomment-168538895).

Comment: Great reference too!